# Audio/Screen Output is lagging every 7 minutes

Tags: windows, windows-10, event-log, lag

I have had this problem since I installed Windows 10 about 2 years ago (new custom PC), but the problem was occuring very rarely until a couple of days ago. I have tried Windows reset, clean install of drivers of audio and video card with no luck. I noticed it is happening every 7 minutes (after updating: December 14, 2021—KB5008212), I also took a look if there was a spike in CPU usage and I saw after every freeze that 3 processes of Windows were running and by the time it was back to normal these processes were back at 0% usage.

Process 1. StorSvc

Process 2. DoSvc

Process 2. EventLog

Upon further searching, I came to the conclusion that these were actually logging the errors, and I noticed that because I ran out of space in just 2 days (after installing the update I mentioned). Almost 60 GB of log files were created in about 2 days.

Also, I have multiple audio devices: the audio freeze happens on all of them so that excludes a specific device. The audio freeze is always happening the same time as the video freeze—it's not a big freeze, about a second or less, but it could happen 4-5 times in the 7th minute.

Some info that maybe helps:

Windows 10 Pro, 21H2.
OS Build: 19044.1415

Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

The error as shown in the event viewer (xml format):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting"/>
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-12-19T11:47:23.0859864Z"/>
    <EventRecordID>129685</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation/>
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0"/>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-XXXXXXX</Computer>
    <Security/>
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data/>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>AppxDeploymentFailureBlue</Data>
    <Data>NONE</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>80070032</Data>
    <Data>13</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>NONE</Data>
    <Data>10.0.19041.1415</Data>
    <Data>495</Data>
    <Data/>
    <Data/>
    <Data/>
    <Data/>
    <Data/>
    <Data/>
    <Data/>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>5f89d0b2-0080-4b60-9f7d-6d9871489901</Data>
    <Data>2147483648</Data>
    <Data/>
    <Data>0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

This is the new error after disabling Internet connection:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-01-09T21:22:44.2702792Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>132339</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-XXXXXXX</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>StoreAgentSearchUpdatePackagesFailure1</Data> 
  <Data>NONE</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>Acquisition;GamingServices</Data> 
  <Data>80240438</Data> 
  <Data>19044</Data> 
  <Data>1415</Data> 
  <Data>Windows.Desktop</Data> 
  <Data>5</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_Acquisition;Gami_2e60c6c4fab4d33a9dccf7977c9fc48acd837f0_00000000_d0c257cf-2f44-4b18-a171-bc0e33860371</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>d0c257cf-2f44-4b18-a171-bc0e33860371</Data> 
  <Data>6</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Regarding the log files filling up the disk, you can set log files to be limited to, say, 20480 KB and to "overwrite events as needed" to keep the latest events.

Comment: Have you tried `sfc /scannow` and `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth` from a "Windows PowerShell (Admin)" command prompt?

Comment: Yes I should have probably mentioned that.I have tried both. I think sfc found some corruptions and fixed them(I cant recall if it was that one or dism) but no luck.

Comment: "AppxDeploymentFailureBlue" appears to be associated with Windows Store, so perhaps something in [8 Common Microsoft Store and App Issues in Windows 10 (With Fixes)](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-tips-fix-windows-store-app-issues-windows-10/) will help.

Comment: If it is some application from the Windows Store trying to update itself, confirm by uninstalling the application, or at least running without internet connectivity for a while.

Comment: So I did all the steps shown in the article but no luck.The step 1.after running the BITS gave me an error and i tried a quick fix i found googling this NET HELPMSG 2182.Still i had no change @AndrewMorton

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I just disable Internet connection as you suggested.I updated my post and I have included a new error occuring when no Internet connection.I am troobleshooting as of this time,and will update if i find a fix.

Comment: Update: I tried everything I could find online but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: @Paner Are the motherboard manufacturer's drivers for the chipset installed? How much hardware can you remove/disconnect (e.g. audio devices)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes.I have the chipset drivers installed(I think I updated them 2-3 months ago too) And I am running the latest versions provided by the manufacturer. I can remove any peripheral device and hard drive connected by usb(except those inside my case,my main SSD drive and a secondary HDD). Th